# Can I move a logical swap partition to primary from the running environment?

Tags: partitioning

I'm trying to establish RAID 1 and `/dev/sda` is my new, identically partitioned HDD, but I get this error returned when trying to assign `sda2` extended partition as Linux raid auto (fd)

> Cannot change type of the extended partition which is already used by logical partitions. Delete logical partitions first.

This seems to be because `sdb5` (and as a result the copied `sda5`) swap partition is a logical partition within `sdb2`. Since I have my box at a different physical location, I'm currently SSH'd on `/dev/sdb` over PuTTY and want to know if it's possible to move this partition to primary from its own running environment/PuTTY. If I have to use a recovery terminal, I can wait but I'd appreciate command help with that too. Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? In general you can not move partitions that are in use. So you could turn swap off and make a new partition outside sda2 for swap, but then you would need to modify /etc/fstab to use the new partition. You could also use a swap file.

Comment: This sounds like what I want. I don't know much about swap partitions but I assumed it'd be healthier to keep it, and you're saying I can turn it off and delete its partition without consequence - then create a new one if I wanted?

Comment: Yes or a swap file. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_a_swap_file.3F

Comment: Personally I do not use swap at all on desktops with > 4 gb RAM , the only exception would be if you are running ram demanding apps such as virtual machines or video editing. In those events I add a swap partition for backup. It really depends on how much RAM you have and how much you use.

Comment: This is an old desktop with 2GB memory hosting a ts3 and apache/phpbb server. No VMs. I think I'll keep a swap file as a backup. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I would keep a 2.1 Gb swap (a little lager than your RAM)

Answer (score 0):

Read `man 8 swapon`, then do something like

```
sudo swapoff /dev/sdb5
```

if swap on `/dev/sda5` isn't enabled (check with `swapon --show`), do

```
sudo swapon /dev/sda5
```

Comment: How does that move anything ? All it does is turn swap off .